# On x86 assembly jump table

Tags: assembly, x86

Sometimes there are jump table like this:

```
operations:
    .long operation1, operation2, operation3
```

Then called by:

```
jmp *operations(,%ecx,4)
```

What I don't really understand is since you declare that number to a long, it's 32 bit, so operation + 4*ecx for ecx being 0,1,2 will translate into adding 0,4,8 which doesn't really equal to 0,32,64. So how does this jump actually occurs.

Comment: I have edited `ecs` into `ecx` since you have tagged this question as x86 and there is no such register as `ecs` in x86 assembly. Is that what you meant? If no, feel free to rollback the edit

Comment: Addresses are in bytes not bits.

Comment: Thank you very much. That answered my question