# Short jump offset table usage

Tags: assembly, x86, jump-table

I am trying to use a table with short jump offsets:

```
        mov     $4, %eax           

j1: 
        movzbl  offset(%eax),%edx   # load jump offset 
        jmp     *(%edx)

r1:
        ...


offset:
        .byte   0, 1, 2, 3, 4       # Example values
```

Objdump shows the jump encoded as `ff 22` which is not a short jump.

I also tried `jmp *r1(%edx)` to jump to label `r1` + an offset based on what I saw in this question: [On x86 assembly jump table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38945588/3163618), but gdb shows that takes me to somewhere completely different in memory.

Another idea is to read `eip` and adding an offset manually as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333437/3163618):

```
    call get_eip
get_eip:
    pop %eax
    add %edx, %eax
```

Ideally the solution is as short as possible for the interest of code golf. So how can I specify a jump table to nearby sections of code while only using 1 byte per offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 doesn't have relative indirect jumps.  You always have to compute (or load) the absolute target address.

`jmp  *(%edx)` uses `%edx` as a pointer, and *loads* a new EIP value from the 32-bit location pointed to by `%edx`.  i.e. it's a memory-indirect jump.

So is `jmp *r1(%edx)`.  The code in the question you linked is `jmp *operations(,%ecx,4)`, which loads a 32-bit target address from a table of pointers.  (That's why it scales the index by 4.)  If EIP was exposed as a general-purpose register, that `jmp` would be `mov r1(%edx), %eip`, so it's unsurprising that using 4 bytes of instructions *as a point* is not useful.

---

To *compute* a target address, you probably want to use a register-indirect jump, like `jmp *%eax`.  That sets EIP to the value of EAX, so the only memory access will be instruction fetch from the new address.

You're obviously using 32-bit mode, so you can't use a RIP-relative LEA for position-independent code.  **But if you can make your code position-dependent, you can use the address of a label as an immediate**.  You're using position-dependent addressing for `offset(%eax)` already (32-bit absolute address as a disp32), so you might as well do that.

```
.section .rodata
    jump_offset: .byte 0, .L2-.L1,  .L3-.L1,  ...

.section .text
    # selector in EAX
    movzbl  jump_offset(%eax), %eax
    add     $.L1, %eax
    jmp     *%eax                # EIP = EAX
    # put the most common label first: when no branch-target prediction is available,
    # the default prediction for an indirect jmp is fall-through.
.L1:
    ...

.L2:
  ...

.L3:     
  ...
```

**If each block is the same size (or you can pad it to the same size), you don't need a table at all; you can just scale the selector**:

```
    # selector in EAX
    lea     .L1(,%eax,8), %eax  # or shift or multiply + add for other sizes
    jmp     *%eax

.p2align 3     # ideally arrange for this to be 0 bytes, by lengthening earlier instructions or padding earlier
.L1: ...

.p2align 3     # pad to a multiple of 8
.L2: ...

.p2align 3
.L3: ...
```

It doesn't *have* to be a power of 2 block size: `lea .L1(%eax,%eax,8), %eax` to scale by 9 and add the base is probably better than wasting 7 bytes per block.  But it means you can't use `.p2align` anymore to help you make each block the same size.  (I think GAS might be able to calculate padding the way NASM can ([`times 9-($-.L1) nop`](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo12.html#section-12.1.3) to insert enough padding bytes to reach 9 bytes beyond `.L1`.  But single-byte NOPs suck if there's more than 1 and they're executed).  Anyway I don't remember the GAS syntax.)

---

In 64-bit PIC code, `lea .L1(%rip), %rdx` / `add %rax, %rdx`.

In 32-bit PIC code, use

```
    call .LPIC_reference_point
.LPIC_reference_point:
    pop   %edx
    movzbl jump_offsets - .LPIC_reference_point(%eax), %eax
    add   %edx, %eax
    jmp   *%eax
```

Or use the GOT for PIC access to static data the way compilers do (look at `gcc -O3 -m32 -fPIE` output.)

([`call +0` does *not* unbalance the return-address predictor stack](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/#call0) on Intel P6 or SnB-family, or AMD K8/Bulldozer.  So `call`/`pop` is safe to use.  Henry doesn't have tests on Silvermont, though, and it does cause a mis-predicts Nano3000.)

Comment: The label subtraction is neat